# Specific question about downsampling in frequency domain

Tags: signal-processing

I'm confused about why Equation 4.74 can be expressed as Equation 4.76 after the summation index is expressed as in Equation 4.75. Could somebody please explain? Thanks!

[Downsampling DTFT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kWZOL.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is just saying that $\sum_r f(r) = \sum_k \sum_{i=0}^{M-1} f(i+kM)$.

(Assuming that the rearrangement is valid, of course).

Comment: Thanks, thought about it some more and it's extremely obvious now. Thanks!